# Pause and Edit Journey - Impact of Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein

I developed a journey that has multiple paths and multiple emails.  I wanted to use Eienstine STO before the emails but then realized that I just want to send the first email right away.

I had already activated the journey before realizing this and there are many contacts now waiting to get the first email-based on STO 24hr schedule and some have already gone past that point.

What happens if I pause this Journey, create a new version and remove the first STO option for the first email?

**Questions to Answer:**

1. What happens to the contacts waiting in STO? Will the email push right away?
2. What happens to those who are in the 3 Week Waiting period?
3. Which contacts will go to the new version, only new entries?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a difference between [**pausing**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_pause_running_journey.htm&type=5) the current version of the journey and creating a new version and then activating it. In short -

> You can pause a particular version or all versions of a journey to halt processing contacts. After a journey is paused, Journey Builder doesn’t create new sends. Contacts processed by Journey Builder and queued for sending aren’t paused.

Based on what you explained, you would create a new version, adjust the activities on the canvas and activate the new one. This will make the previous version have "Finishing" status, which presumes contacts will remain in that version until they exit or the version is fully stopped.

**Answering your questions:**

1. As I said above, after the creation and activation of a new version with the correct flow, contacts in the previous version will go according to the structure, thus they would:

   - Wait STO --> Get an email --> Wait 3 weeks --> Wait STO --> Exit after 1 day of waiting
2. Same as the first answer, they will wait and go according to the flow.
3. Contacts that are within the previous version would be still there and that old version will not accept any new entries. The most recent and activated version will accept new contacts and send them into an adjusted flow. However, it would depend also on the [Contact Entry](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_choose_a_contact_entry_mode.htm&type=5) setting - if it is `Re-entry at any time` then your contacts might re-enter the journey in a new version and still be in the old version, hence you would send emails twice.

Comment: SUPER HELPFUL!!!  This is was I was hoping to read but wanted to verify.

I have my Journey settings to "No re-entry", so we should be fine for FUTURE leads.  THANK YOU!

Comment: You are welcome, do not forget to choose an [answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark :)

Comment: Thanks!  Accepted :)

Comment: This worked GREAT!  Thanks again, sir!

Comment: you were such a help before can you help here :)
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/354765/95718